# How to implement rogue-lite skill system

Tags: unity, c#, software-engineering

I am creating a roguelike/lite game where in a player has a freedom to learn a number of skills.

For example, I have a projectile skills and I can learn three different behaviours.

- Behavior 1: shoot multiple projectiles in a straight line.
- Behavior 2: shoot multiple projectiles outwards in a circle.
- Behavior 3: shoot projectiles in a cone in front of you.

Structure wise I have thought of using:

- skills = scriptable objects
- skill manager = handles execution, skill tree and more.

My question is: what is the best way to approach programming each of the skills?

- Would it be best for example to create multiple separate classes that handle each of the behaviors individually?
- Or would it be better just to use "skill" class to include these behaviors/methods?
- Or is there any better way to approach this?

Comment: How many skills do you have in total? Are they upgradeable? Like basic skill is shooting straight and one upgrade makes it a double shoot or circle shoot?

Comment: I am still in the prototype stage and have about 30 listed as of now. Might well go over 100 if I made it into a full game. So other skills might not only affect projectile (e.gcould be player movement, etc.). I wanted to know the best way to go about systematic approach to coding different behavior for different skills than getting the exact way to code the examples I have mentioned.

Comment: Are there some skills that exclude each other? Like one makes you shooting wiggling, the other in a zickzack pattern. Also some upgrades are easier than others, a player increase upgrade would just need to find the player and increase once the speed compared to an upgrade that split shots on hit. I probably would make it on an event based system but before starting I would write down as many upgrades as possible to make sure the system could actually handle it

Comment: There is never a "best" way to accomplish something. Only the best way for you and your game.

Answer (score 2):

I would approach a flexible game element system with a mix of game managers, gameobjects and events. These are basic types of upgrades usually found in most games:

- Changes in numeric values
- Changes in functionality
- Added functionality that is independent from existing behaviour
- Replaced functionality of a basic skill
- any combination of the three above in a single upgrade

The first upgrade is the easiest to handle. One game manager that has all numeric values that are changeable. Our upgrade itself knows which value gets changes and by how much. It grabs the value from the game manager and adds it change on top. If the upgrade is temporary, on deactivation you remove the added value again. Typical upgrades under this category are max health, movementspeed, crit chance and dmg.

Example code for max health (the code is just written down, the Managers are basic static ones and need more code itself, code is untested)

```
public class HealthBonus: MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField]
    private float bonusAmount;
    
    void Start() {
        StatsManager.instance.maxHealth += bonusAmount;
        PlayerManager.instance.currentHealth += bonusAmount;
    }

    private void OnDestroy() {
        StatsManager.instance.maxHealth -= bonusAmount;
    }
}
```

The second upgrade is taking an existing behaviour and adds something on top of it. I'm going to use life steal as an example. The code that handles the collision between enemy and bullets is just calling an event like OnEnemyHit.invoke(dmgAmount). Your life steal gameobject adds a listener to the current OnEnemyHit event and can have all the logic inside itself where to add that life and how much. Other examples would be like want to add bullets shooting side ways? Add listener to the OnShoot. Want to add an explosion when dmg taken? Add listener to OnDmgTaken. While this is going to add one more call of the default behaviour (you are not calling a Shoot() directly but you have a shoot event and your shoot logic it listening to the shoot event), this gives you a lot of flexibility. If the upgrade is just temporary, when the time is up just remove again the listener.

A basic enemy would look usually something along the lines of this

```
public class Enemy: MonoBehaviour {

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other) {
        if(other.gameObject.CompareTag("PlayerProjectile"))
            GetComponent<EnemyLife>().dealDmg(StatsManager.instance.currentDmg);
    }
}
```

The inbetween over the event system could look something like this

```
//Change of handling the hit in dmg, we pass it to the CombatManager
public class Enemy: MonoBehaviour {

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other) {
        if(other.gameObject.CompareTag("PlayerProjectile"))
            CombatManager.instance.OnEnemyHit.Invoke(gameObject, StatsManager.instance.currentDmg);
    }
}

//Same behaviour as before
public class CombatManager: MonoBehaviour {
    
    public static CombatManager instance;
    public UnityEvent<GameObject, float> OnEnemyHit;

    void Start() {
        instance.OnEnemyHit.AddListener(HandleEnemyHit);
    }

    private void HandleEnemyHit(GameObject enemy, float dmgValue) {
        enemy.GetComponent<EnemyLife>().dealDmg(dmgValue);
    }
}

//But now we can put in extra code without changing the original 
public class LifeSteal: MonoBehaviour {

    private float lifeStealValue = 0.1f;
    
    void Start() {
        CombatManager.instance.OnEnemyHit.AddListener(StealLife);
    }

    private void OnDestroy() {
        CombatManager.instance.OnEnemyHit.RemoveListener(StealLife);
    }

    private void StealLife(GameObject enemy, float hitDmg) {
        PlayerManager.instance.currentHealth += hitDmg * lifeStealValue;
    }
}
```

The added functionality that is independent upgrade is a self containing game object that has all the logic it needs but is not a current modification. For example one upgrade adds a spinning circle around the player. Or a small drone that starts shooting at enemies and follows the player. If this is temporary again, it just delete the gameobject after the time is up.

If you want to replace a basic functionality (say instead of shooting straight they curve now or your shots are homing), this is really similar to the life steal code. The only difference is that you first remove the listener of the basic function of shooting straight and plug in your replacement effect.

Of course it is possible to mix the upgrades as well.